# How do I check how much memory a Mediawiki instance has available to it?

Tags: configuration, mediawiki

Before anyone posts something about checking php.ini, bear in mind there are all sorts of ways it could be overridden. Where's the admin page or panel that lists the amount of RAM available to mediawiki?

(Due diligence: Searches turned up nothing. Proof in links below)

https://www.google.com/search?q=mediawiki+admin+panel&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1
only relevant link is https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:System_administration
which contains nothing about memory or RAM

https://www.google.com/search?q=mediawiki+admin+UI+how+much+memory+is+allocated&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1
again nothing

https://www.google.com/search?q=mediawiki+how+to+check+how+much+memory+is+allocated&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1
again, nothing. First link suggests increasing amount of RAM but that isn't useful if my php.ini is being ignored for unknown reasons

Comment: Put `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in a `.php` file, load it in the browser, and see what `php.ini` file(s) it's looking for. Are you running into an "out of memory" error?

Comment: Yes. I need to find how much RAM my wiki instance has and preferably where it's being set. Spaghetti code/configuration sucks!

Comment: What problem are you working to solve? PHP has a per-request memory limit you can set. There's also *concurrency* to consider - how many PHP processes are running at once. It'd help if you added more details on what problem you've encountered.

Comment: Web request on some pages running into an error - request for 18 MB and only 128 MB is available. I found and updated several php memory limits (both php.ini and LocalSettings ini_set) and they are all being ignored (revisiting the page after updating the RAM limits always produces the out of memory, 128 MB available error)

Comment: OK, so you're going to want to  do the technique I suggested with `phpinfo` to see where your `.ini` files are.

Comment: Found a .ini file connected to a Docker shared object (.so) file although I have a 256 MB limit specified in LocalSettings which should override that.

Comment: Inspected the other LocalSettings and none of them contain ini_set for memory limits. As far as I know, the only specified memory limit on the install is 1 GB in php.ini and it's giving 128MB anyway. Does anyone know if I can use a memory editor to edit the limit on the PHP engine (in-memory)? At this rate it will be faster to set up a memory editor and change the 128M to 1GB than track down why Mediawiki ignores all memory limit commands.

Comment: You could try to set [`$wgMemoryLimit`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgMemoryLimit).